# I can't copy content from an html tag into another django template

Tags: html, django

Good night friends.
I'm trying to display the content of a tag in a template, in another template, using the django "extends" method. Works perfectly with when it comes to "normal", "typed" content:

this works:

```
{% block part_of_site %}
   <div id='tag2'>Context</div>
{% endblock %}
```

using a variable, you can't copy to another template:

```
{% block part_of_site %}
   <div id='tag2'>{{ variable }}</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How are you passing the variable into the template? Show the view?

Comment: the variable is not called in the view. It is in another view function, and I need to show its result in another template. I tried this way as in the code above, but it doesn't copy the result. But copying other information, as in the first code, it copies correctly, and shows it in the other template.

Comment: Explaining, the copy I tried to make was by JS, trying to capture the result of the variable and pasting it in another tag, and then using the "extends" feature to view it in another template. But he can't copy the result...

Comment: the result I need, in short, is: show the content of a variable from a template, in another template...

Comment: Do you think [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include) might be what you need? Particularly combined with `with`? Sorry if I just don't understand your question.